# CSS define class name and pseudo selector at once

Tags: css

I'm a newbie to front-end development and am trying to clean up my css. This seems to be a really simple question, but is there a way to define a class and pseudo-selector at once? I want to take the below code:

```
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.blue:hover {
  opacity: .1;
}
```

and write it in a more contained way, I'm thinking something like this:

```
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
  &:hover {
    opacity: .1;
  }
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're after is exactly what [scss](https://sass-lang.com) provides, it's a css preprocessor.
Other than that there isn't yet a native way to achieve this in pure css